# Django Create and Save Many instances of model when another object are created

Tags: python, django

I am designing a game of chess and I would like to initialize the fields with chess figures (State model) after the start of a new `ChessParty`.
I read about overriding the `save()` model method, but I don't know how to use it in my case. 
 
I am reading about signals like `post_save`, but I have the same problem.

Something like this could work?

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        (Here i want create many instances of another Model)
    super(ChessParty, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And here is my code so far:

```
class ChessParty(models.Model):
    chessparty_id = models.AutoField("ID partii", primary_key=True)
    arbiter = models.ForeignKey(Arbiter, related_name='sedzia', 
    verbose_name="Sędzia")
    white = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='Białe', 
    verbose_name="Białe figury")
    black = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='Czarne', 
    verbose_name="Czarne figury")
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, verbose_name="Nazwa turnieju")

    def __str__(self):
        return "{white} vs {black}, ({tournament})"\
            .format(black=self.black, white=self.white, tournament=self.tournament)


class OneMove(models.Model):
party = models.ForeignKey(ChessParty, default='0', verbose_name="Partia")
chessman = (
    ('a1_w_rook', 'biała wieża a1'), ('h1_w_rook', 'biała wieża h1'),
    ('b1_w_knight', 'biały skoczek b1'), ('g1_w_knight', 'biały skoczek g1'),
    ('c1_w_bishop', 'biały goniec c1'), ('f1_w_bishop', 'biały goniec f1'),
    ('d1_w_queen', 'biały hetman d1'), ('e1_w_king', 'biały król e1'),
    ('a2_w_pawn', 'biały pion a2'), ('b2_w_pawn', 'biały pion b2'),
    ('c2_w_pawn', 'biały pion c2'), ('d2_w_pawn', 'biały pion d2'),
    ('e2_w_pawn', 'biały pion e2'), ('f2_w_pawn', 'biały pion f2'),
    ('g2_w_pawn', 'biały pion g2'), ('h2_w_pawn', 'biały pion h2'),
    ('a8_b_rook', 'czarna wieża a1'), ('h8_b_rook', 'czarna wieża h8'),
    ('b8_b_knight', 'czarny skoczek b1'), ('g8_b_knight', 'czarny skoczek g8'),
    ('c8_b_knight', 'czarny goniec c1'), ('f8_b_bishop', 'czarny goniec f8'),
    ('d8_b_queen', 'czarny hetman d1'), ('e8_b_king', 'czarny król e8'),
    ('a7_b_pawn', 'czarny pion a7'), ('b7_b_pawn', 'czarny pion b7'),
    ('c7_b_pawn', 'czarny pion c7'), ('d7_b_pawn', 'czarny pion d7'),
    ('e7_b_pawn', 'czarny pion e7'), ('f7_b_pawn', 'czarny pion f7'),
    ('g7_b_pawn', 'czarny pion g7'), ('h7_b_pawn', 'czarny pion h7'),
 )
chessman = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=chessman, default='pionek', verbose_name="Figura Szachowa")
mymove = []
for a, b in itertools.product('abcdefgh', '12345678'):
    name = a + b
    mymove.append((name, name))
mytuple = tuple(mymove)
move = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=mytuple, default='a1', verbose_name="Ruch na")

class Meta:
    abstract = True


class State(OneMove):
state_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="numer ruchu")
is_capture = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Czy zbita")
capture_choice = (
    ('true', 'zbity'),
    ('false', 'nie zbity'),
)
is_capture = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=capture_choice, default='false', verbose_name="Czy zbity")
```

Comment: what i don't understand is what has django got to do with chess? Or are you perhaps designing a human vs human interface for chess website?

Comment: @e4c5 This is supposed to be platform for management Chess competition, the judge makes moves, and wiewers watch them.
This is a college project to use the database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Using `save()`:**

If you want to use the `save()` method, you could do the following:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    OtherModel.objects.create(something=kwargs['something'])
    YetAnotherModel.objects.create(
        something_else=kwargs['something_else']
    )
    super(ChessParty, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

As @e4c5 states in his comment, it is easier to implement and that is why I include it!

---

**My take on the problem:**

Although you could do this on the `save()`, I would recommend instead to use a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/).

Specifically use a [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save) signal. Here is how to do this:

1. Create a file `your_app/signals.py`:

   ```
   from django.db.models.signals import post_save
   from django.dispatch import receiver

   from your_app.models import ChessParty, OtherModel, YetAnotherModel


   @receiver(post_save, sender=ChessParty)
   def change_my_name_plz (sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
       if created:
           OtherModel.objects.create(something=kwargs['something'])
           YetAnotherModel.objects.create(
               something_else=kwargs['something_else']
           )
   ```
2. You now need to override the `ready()` function on `your_app/app.py`:

   ```
   from django.apps import AppConfig

   class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
       name = 'your_project.your_app'

       def ready(self):
           import your_project.your_app.signals
   ```
3. Finally, add the following in `your_app/__init__.py`:

   ```
   default_app_config = 'your_project.your_app.apps.YourAppConfig'
   ```

Now you have a signal that will create an `OtherModel` and `YetAnotherModel` objects right after you create a new `ChessParty` object.

---

**Alternative way to define signals:**

There is an alternative way that does not use the `@receiver` decorator, but the [`connect()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.Signal.connect) method:

1. `your_app/signals.py`:

   ```
   from your_app.models import ChessParty, OtherModel, YetAnotherModel


   def change_my_name_plz (sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
       if created:
           OtherModel.objects.create(something=kwargs['something'])
           YetAnotherModel.objects.create(
               something_else=kwargs['something_else']
           )
   ```
2. `your_app/app.py`:

   ```
   from django.apps import AppConfig
   from django.db.models.signals import post_save

   from your_app.models import ChessParty
   from your_project.your_app.signals import change_my_name_plz

   class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
       name = 'your_project.your_app'

       def ready(self):
           post_save.connect(change_my_name_plz, sender=ChessParty)
   ```
3. `your_app/__init__.py` stays the same as above (step 3).

---

Comment: Using signals does not give any specific advantage here. `save` does the job equally well (or poorly)

Comment: but save has the advantage of being simpler to implement

Comment: @e4c5 that is true and I edited my answer to include the `save()` way

Comment: even though easiest solution for OP is to modify `save()` it is always nice to keep signals mentioned everywhere as sometimes we do not control the model that should trigger the creation of the other model :) +1