# How to send a django signal from other signal

Tags: python, django, django-signals

**TL;DR:** 
I need a way to trigger a custom signal after the `post_save` signal, automatically, is there any way of doing it?

---

I'm currently developing a library for django that requires a lot of comes and goes with the `post_save` signal in django and I was wondering if it's possible to trigger another signal **after** the `post_save` so I could implement my own and not intervene the `post_save` in case a project that uses the library needs to do it.

So far I know that signals are expected to receive a class as a sender argument, and if I trigger manually the signal from the post_save I would be doing nothing (I'd still be intervening it). Is there any workaround for this? Am I missing something in the docs?

Comment: *Why* do you need a custom signal? If what you need to do happens every time something is saved, then just use the `post_save` signal. It doesn't matter whether or not you use all the arguments that are passed to the signal handler.

Comment: Hey, @OscarCarballal I was wondering, did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I completely forgot about marking it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this may be possible by calling a signal manually from inside another signal like this:

```
post_save.send(MyModel, instance=a_mymodel_instance)
```

There are easier ways to do something like that:

*Let us assume that you follow the file organization that I use in this answer: [Django Create and Save Many instances of model when another object are created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451771/django-create-and-save-many-instances-of-model-when-another-object-are-created/44453226#44453226)*

---

**Suggestion 1:**

- Let us assume that your first `post_save` does something to `MyModel1` and another `post_save` signal does something to `MyModel2` after some processing on the instance that triggered the first signal.
- [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save) is always send at the **end** of a `save()` method.
- Organize your signals as follows:

  ```
  @receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel1)
  def mymodel1_signal (sender, instance, **kwargs):
      Do stuff on MyModel1 instance...
      Do also stuff on MyModel2 and then call MyModel2.save()


  @receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel2)
  def mymodel2_signal (sender, instance, **kwargs):
      Do stuff on MyModel2 instance...
  ```

  This way the `mymodel2_signal` signal will get triggered after the call to `MyModel2.save()` from `mymodel1_signal`.

---

**Suggestion 2:**

- Use a mix of signals to achieve the correct "timing".
- Let us assume that you want to start a process on `MyModel2` before a `MyModel1` get's saved
- Use a [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#pre-save) and a `post_save` signal:

  ```
  @receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel1)
  def mymodel1_signal (sender, instance, **kwargs):
      Do stuff on MyModel1 instance...
      Do also stuff on MyModel2 and then call MyModel2.save()


  @receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel2)
  def mymodel2_signal (sender, instance, **kwargs):
      Do stuff on MyModel2 instance...
  ```

---

**Suggestion 3:**

Use a `MyModel2` method directly inside a `MyModel1` `post_save` signal.

Comment: when  operating many instances ,we may use django channel to triger a offline task to do it.

Comment: @Hayden I do not have experience at the moment with django-channels. So what you say seems interesting :)