# Improve the calculation of distances between objects in queryset

Tags: python, django, gis, postgis, geodjango

I have next models in my Django project:

```py
class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=100, unique=True)
    ...

class Zone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('name'),
                            max_length=100,
                            unique=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area,
                             verbose_name=_('area'),
                             db_index=True)
    polygon = PolygonField(srid=4326,
                           verbose_name=_('Polygon'),)
    ...
```

The `Area` is like a city, and the `Zone` is like a district.

So, I want to cache for every zone what is the order with other zones of its area. Something like this:

```py
def store_zones_by_distance():
    zones = {}
    zone_qs = Zone.objects.all()
    for zone in zone_qs:
        by_distance = Zone.objects.filter(area=zone.area_id).distance(zone.polygon.centroid).order_by('distance').values('id', 'name', ...)
        zones[zone.id] = [z for z in by_distance]
    cache.set("zones_by_distance", zones, timeout=None)
```

But the problem is that it is not efficient and it is not scalable. We have 382 zones, and this function gets 383 queries to DB, and it is very slow (3.80 seconds in SQL time and 4.20 seconds in global time).

is there any way efficient and scalable to get it. I had thought in something like this:

```py
def store_zones_by_distance():
    zones = {}
    zone_qs = Zone.objects.all()
    for zone in zone_qs.prefetch_related(Prefetch('area__zone_set', queryset=Zone.objects.all().distance(F('polygon__centroid')).order_by('distance'))):
        by_distance = zone.area.zone_set.all().values('id', 'name', ...)
        zones[zone.id] = [z for z in by_distance]
```

This obviously does not work, but something like this, caching in SQL (prefetch related) the zones ordered (area__zone_set).

**EDIT** store_zones_by_distance will return (or set in cache) something like this:

```py
{
    1: [{"id": 1, "name": "Zone 1"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Zone 2"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Zone 4"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Zone 3"}],
    2: [{"id": 2, "name": "Zone 2"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Zone 4"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Zone 1"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Zone 3"}],
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do a nested prefetch resulting in 3 queries.

```
def store_zones_by_distance():
    area_qs = Area.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
        'zone_set',
        queryset=Zone.objects.annotate(
            distance=F('polygon__centroid')
        ).order_by('distance')
    ))
    zones = Zone.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch(
        'area',
        queryset=area_qs,
        to_attr='prefetched_area'
    ))

    zones_dict = {}
    for zone in zones:
        zones_dict[zone.id] = zone.prefetched_area.zone_set
```

**Update** using the function from *@JohnMoutafis* in combination with `django.forms.model_to_dict` to accomplish your expected output in 2 queries.

```
from django.db.models import F, Prefetch
from django.forms import model_to_dict

def store_zones_by_distance():
    zones = {}
    areas = Area.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
        'zone_set',
        queryset=Zone.objects.annotate(
            distance=Centroid('polygon')
        ).order_by('distance')
    ))

    for area in areas:
        for zone in area.zone_set.all():
            zones[zone.id] = [
                model_to_dict(zone, fields=['id', 'name'])
                for zone in area.zone_set.all()
            ]
```

Comment: Thanks this monday will test your solution and if this works i will close the bounty!

Comment: Please see two comments in the answer of JohnMoutafis. Your solution has the same problems that another solution.

Comment: I've update my solution. The same logic could be applied to the original nested prefetch but I figured you'd want to do it with the least amount of queries. Not sure how scalable this is with the loops.

Comment: I'm sorry but I get next error: "ValueError: Cannot use object with type F for a spatial lookup parameter."

Comment: @Goin that's weird because it's the same annotation as was in your OP and I was under the impression that was working. I've updated my code answer based on your other comment. If the updated annotation doesn't work you'll have to figure it out on your end. To test that the code provides the expected output, although unsorted, you can remove the annotation and run the function.

Comment: You can see in my question: "I had thought in something like this:" But, I tried to say: "I had thought in something like this, but this does not work" I thought it was understood, but I was wrong :-P

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** Since our back and forth I believe that we can find a viable solution for this problem.

You need to case the zones ordered by the distance between them. That doesn't need to happen many times as far as I understand (hence you are using a cache).
Essentially you need this cache to be set once when the server starts and every time a new zone is updated (added, deleted, patched, etc.) on the DB.

We can use the [`AppConfig.ready()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) function to set the cache on server start and then we can create a [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-save) and a [`post_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-delete) signal for the zone update case.

Let's compose the utility method that we will use in those two cases:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.forms import model_to_dict

def store_zones_by_distance():
    zones = {}
    areas = Area.objects.prefetch_related(`zone_set`).all()

    for area in areas:
        for zone in area.zone_set.all():
            ordered_zones = area.zone_set.filter(~Q(id=zone.id)).distance(
                zone.polygon.centroid
            ).order_by('distance')

            zones[zone.id] = [
               model_to_dict(ordered_zone, fields=['id', 'name'])
               for ordered_zone in ordered_zones
            ]
    cache.set("zones_by_distance", zones, timeout=None)
```

*Method Explanation:*

- The `ordered_zones` will return all the zones except the one we are currently examining (hence the `filter(~Q(id=zone.id))` which translates to "filter the zones whose id is **NOT** the id of the current zone") ordered by the distance of their centroid to the current zones centroid.
- Utilizing @bdoubleu `model_to_dict` suggestion we are creating a list of model instances in dictionary representation.
- The end result for each zone will look like: `[{"id": 1, "name": "Zone 1"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Zone 2"}, ...]`

Now we need to create the `post_save` and `post_delete` signals and connect everything to the `AppConfig.ready()` function (essentially we will follow the steps described here: [Django Create and Save Many instances of model when another object are created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451771/django-create-and-save-many-instances-of-model-when-another-object-are-created/44453226#44453226) with a slight twist).

*I assume that the `store_zones_by_distance` is created in `your_app/utils.py` (you may create it wherever you want though)*:

1. Create the `post_save` and `post_delete` signals in `your_app/signals.py`:

   ```
   from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
   from django.dispatch import receiver

   from your_app.models import Zone
   from your_app.utils import store_zones_by_distance


   @receiver(post_save, sender=Zone)
   def update_added_zone_cache(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
       store_zones_by_distance()

   @receiver(post_delete, sender=Zone)
   def update_removed_zone_cache(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
       store_zones_by_distance()
   ```
2. Run the `store_zones_by_distance` on server start and connect the signals, in `your_app/app.py`:

   ```
   class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
       name = 'your_project.your_app'

       def ready(self):
           import your_project.your_app.signals
           # Run it once at server start
           store_zones_by_distance()
   ```

You will not save on queries much with this, but you will have a cache ready without blocking any of your endpoints until it updates.

---

**I will leave this here for comment legacy reasons, but it is NOT the solution @Goin wanted.**

You are pretty close to a good solution I believe.
As you have already had in your attempt of a more optimized solution, [you can access the foreign key related objects with the `_set` notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/relations/). In your case, you can access the `Zones` from an `Area` using `zones_set`. 
The `_set` allows you to apply any queryset method on it as normal.

Now to avoid the multiple DB hits we need to construct [a custom `Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) were we will add the `polygon__centroid` distance as an annotation.
So with those said, let's make it happen:

```
def store_zones_by_distance():
    zones = {}
    areas = Area.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            `zone_set`,
            queryset=Zone.object.all().annotate(
                centroid_distance=Centroid('polygon')
            ).order_by('centroid_distance')
        )
    ).all()

    for area in areas:
        for zone in area.zone_set.all():
            zones[zone.id] = area.zone_set.all().values_list('id', 'name', ...)
```

That will result in a single query towards the DB that will fetch everything you need for your method.
**EDIT:** *As @bdoubleu mentioned, the `values_list` will cause an extra query per zone so you may want to ditch that and keep the queryset as is in the dictionary `zones[zone.id] = area.zone_set.all()`*.
Keep in mind though that with 2 `for` that may be still time-consuming.

Comment: Calling `.values_list()` will cause an extra query for each zone so hopefully he can find a solution around using that. Otherwise this answer seems to be the best at 2 queries *vs* my answer's 3 queries. Also zone_set is a queryset instead of a list.

Comment: @bdoubleu Good point! He should probably ditch the `values_list` all together!

Comment: Thanks I will test your solution next monday and if this works I will close the bounty!

Comment: Hi @JohnMoutafis. Your solution does not works, for three reasons. First I get next error: "FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'centroid' into field. Join on 'polygon' not permitted." But I can fix it: "annotate(centroid_distance=Centroid('polygon'))". Second error you are order for the center of polygon (polygon__centroid) and I want order by *distance* between zones, but I can fix it too: "area.zone_set.all().distance(zone.polygon.centroid).order_by('distance').values_list('id', 'name', ...)"....

Comment: ... But third your solution gets a dictonary of querysets, and I need a dictionary of lists. For this reason, your solution only execute two queries. In fact, your solution does not  decrease the num of queries, you only are not run these queries, but if you set in cache this: "cache.set("zones_by_distance", zones, timeout=None)" every query will be run

Comment: @Goin Then you simply cannot simplify that. Have you considered simplifying your solution? I also edited the `Centroid('polygon') ` in my answer.

Comment: It is possible that it is a problem without a better solution that my current solution (Although I don't believe it.). I can not simplify the solution because it is not a teoric question, this resolve a problem.

Comment: @Goin Can you please explain how are you going to use the list of `zones` in order for me to understand and possibly provide a solution?

Comment: @JohnMoutafis Thanks! After your question, we will delete this solution. And we are working to address the problem with another way.

Comment: @Goin We may find a viable solution with less refactoring though :)

Comment: Hopefully! Tell me if you find a viable solution! Thanks for all!!

Comment: @Goin I have updated my answer, hope this gets you were you need :)

Comment: Hi @JohnMoutafis with your new solution I get the same queries than with my solution... So it is not a solution :-(

Comment: @Goin It is an automated solution with which you don't need to manually update the cache and it is not blocking for any of your endpoints for the time it takes to execute.

Comment: Yes, basically it is our current solution. But we use celery for it. We cache the zones first time when celery starts and we have signals for recalculate zones when one of them change (center of polygon more than 1 meter). Also in this case, when our code calls to store_zones_by_distance, add the area like parameter... We want a solution to improve it. Thanks a lot, but you have reached the same conclusion as us :-P

Comment: @Goin I was going to suggest celery as an alternative :P. Yes, you should probably simplify the solution if it is possible. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

sorry, I can't comment because I am quite new, so I have to write the suggestion in here.
In your first example:

> ```
> def store_zones_by_distance():
>     zones = {}
>     zone_qs = Zone.objects.all()
>     for zone in zone_qs:
>         by_distance = Zone.objects.filter(area=zone.area_id).distance(zone.polygon.centroid).order_by('distance').values('id', 'name', ...)
>         zones[zone.id] = [z for z in by_distance]
>     cache.set("zones_by_distance", zones, timeout=None)
> ```

It would be interesting how long it would take when you change:

```
zone_qs = Zone.objects.all()
```

[to:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
zone_qs = Zone.objects.all().prefetch_related("area")
```

and

```
by_distance = Zone.objects.filter(area=zone.area_id).distance...
```

[to:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)

```
by_distance = zone_qs.objects.filter(area=zone.area_id).distance...
```

Hope I could give something useful to this topic.

Comment: Thanks @swydngr but it is not a solution. I get a SQL query more than my solution and a very little increase in time.